# Why do batch files sometimes stall until you hit Enter?

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I've seen many times that .BAT files seem to have hung, but if I hit Enter or Ctrl-C or something (not entirely sure) they will spring back to life.
Often the same file will run fine most times without intervention, but get 'stuck' another time... these scripts typically do NOT have user interaction built in.

It's happened enough to make me wonder if the Windows Cmd tool has some sort of feature/bug causing this, separate to the files themselves.

Does anyone know if there's any truth for this, or what might be going on. I cannot share a sample files since a)they're private internal company scripts b)as I said it doesn't seem to be specific to a single script, it's not deterministic as far as I can tell.

Comment: Batch files never stall unless they are waiting for user action. Without an example of such a file the question is unanswerable.

Comment: @harrymc see the answer from Mokubai. Seems someone can answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Batch files will "stall" if you accidentally click-and-drag in the window, as if you are selecting text.  It is roughly equivalent to pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>.

Pressing enter or right-clicking your mouse will deselect the text and the console will carry on.

It happens more often if you click in the window to bring the console forwards while it is scrolling. If you simply <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to the window or bring it forward by clicking the title bar then you will likely not see this behaviour.

Comment: interesting. I use a trackpad and it is sometimes prone to 'dragging' and selecting text without my intention, so this would align with your answer. I'll see if I can 'prove' this is the cause.

Comment: That is where my main experience comes from to be honest. Using a proper mouse it happens a lot less for me.